# Rails route /c/old/?id=x to a redirect to /c/new/x

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Can anyone tell me how to define a Rails 4.2 route which **redirects**

`observer/show_obs?id=x` to

`observer/show_observation/x`

Answer (score 0):

I never did it directly using rails routing, but did through the server. I was using nginx server and added `proxy_pass` for the route.

```
location = /observer/show_obs {
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_pass http://serverName.com/observer/show_observation;
proxy_redirect off;
```

}

Comment: Interesting idea, but won't help in my situation.  

What about a **route** which simply redirects to a different action (same controller, same params), i.e.

`observer/show_obs?id=x` to

`observer/show_observation/?id=x`

Comment: redirecting from controller action is always an option, but i dont think its a good idea.

Comment: If it's "always an option", please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I meant, You can have a controller action corresponding to route : `observer/show_obs?id=x` which redirects the request to route `observer/show_observation/?id=x` which is handled by another controller action.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  But the defined controller action `show_obs` is exactly what I'm trying to avoid -- I wan to do it by routes.